# Rename war generated using AWS cli for beanstalk deployment

Tags: git, bash, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using this script for deploying the war from jenkins to elastic beanstalk, check this link, https://github.com/ayush/eb-deploy/blob/master/eb-deploy
, the script is working properly but one thing I need to modify is the version label of the uploaded war, currently it is renaming the build to something git-${a random number} , I need to provide a custom version label that should be auto increment on each build.

Answer (score 0):

The [eb-deploy](https://github.com/ayush/eb-deploy/blob/master/eb-deploy) script can be called using the `-v` argument, to specify  a custom build number. You can use the [jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project) `BUILD_NUMBER` environment variable to get get an auto increment value on each build.

Just try to append the `-v ${BUILD_NUMBER}` as an argument to `eb-deploy`.

Comment: Actually the -v argument specify the label for build which jenkins create , not the one we are pushing to beanstalk.

Comment: @user29578 If you check the `147` line from the script you will see that: `WAR=$APP_WAR.$CI_BUILD_NUMBER.war` and `CI_BUILD_NUMBER` value  can be set with `-v` from line `59`. If not set then the value will be set at line 117.

Comment: Please check the next line 149, that it is the version jenkins looking for echo "War file not found at $WAR. eb-deploy looks at (\$APP_WAR or -w).(\$CI_BUILD_NUMBER or -v).war" , not the one which to be pushed at , its configuration are somewhere after line 218 , but not able to figure out